# numpy.sum on range and range_iterator objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, ipython

Consider this performance test on Ipython under python 3:

Create a range, a range_iterator and a generator

```
In [1]: g1 = range(1000000)

In [2]: g2 = iter(range(1000000))

In [3]: g3 = (i for i in range(1000000))
```

Measure time for summing using python native sum

```
In [4]: %timeit sum(g1)
10 loops, best of 3: 47.4 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit sum(g2)
The slowest run took 374430.34 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 123 ns per loop

In [6]: %timeit sum(g3)
The slowest run took 1302907.54 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 128 ns per loop
```

Not sure if I should worry about the warning. The range version timing is vary long (why?), but the range_iterator and the generator are similar.

Now let's use numpy.sum

```
In [7]: import numpy as np

In [8]: %timeit np.sum(g1)
10 loops, best of 3: 174 ms per loop

In [9]: %timeit np.sum(g2)
The slowest run took 8.47 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.51 µs per loop

In [10]: %timeit np.sum(g3)
The slowest run took 9.59 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 446 ns per loop
```

g1 and g3 became x~3.5 slower, but the range_iterator g2 is now some ~50 times slower compared to the native sum. g3 wins.

```
In [11]: type(g1)
Out[11]: range

In [12]: type(g2)
Out[12]: range_iterator

In [13]: type(g3)
Out[13]: generator
```

Why such a penalty to range_iterator on numpy.sum? Should such objects be avoided? Does it generalized - Do "home made" generators always beat other objects on numpy?

**EDIT 1:** I realized that the np.sum does not evaluate the range_iterator but returns another range_iterator object. So this comparison is not good. Why doesn't it get evaluated?

**EDIT 2:** I also realized that numpy.sum keeps the range in integer form and accordingly gives the wrong results on my sum due to integer overflow.

```
In [12]: sum(range(1000000))
Out[12]: 499999500000

In [13]: np.sum(range(1000000))
Out[13]: 1783293664

In [14]: np.sum(range(1000000), dtype=float)
Out[14]: 499999500000.0
```

Intermediate conclusion - **don't use numpy.sum on non numpy objects...?**

Comment: This is reiterating a previous similar question that was marked off-topic. Hopefully you'll find this one on-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are Python's arrays slow?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36778568/why-are-pythons-arrays-slow)

Comment: @SSDMS - that answer is for `import array`, not `import numpy`.

Comment: Since you are using Ipython, use `np.sum??` to look at its code.  Except for the special case of a `generator` (not iterator), `np.sum` operates on the `np.array` version of the input.  So if `np.sum` behavior puzzles you, look at `np.array(arg)`.

Answer (score 3):

Did you look at the results of repeated sums on the iter?

```
95:~/mypy$ g2=iter(range(10))
96:~/mypy$ sum(g2)
Out[96]: 45
97:~/mypy$ sum(g2)
Out[97]: 0
98:~/mypy$ sum(g2)
Out[98]: 0
```

Why the 0s?  Because `g2` can be use only once.  Same goes for the generator expression.

Or look at it with list

```
100:~/mypy$ g2=iter(range(10))
101:~/mypy$ list(g2)
Out[101]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
102:~/mypy$ list(g2)
Out[102]: []
```

In Python 3, `range` is a range object, not a list.  So it's an iterator that regenerates each time it is used.

As for `np.sum`, `np.sum(range(10))` has to make an array first.

When operating on a list, the Python `sum` is quite fast, faster than `np.sum` on the same:

```
116:~/mypy$ %%timeit x=list(range(10000))
       ...: sum(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 202 µs per loop

117:~/mypy$ %%timeit x=list(range(10000))
       ...: np.sum(x)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.62 ms per loop
```

But operating on an array, `np.sum` does much better

```
118:~/mypy$ %%timeit x=np.arange(10000)
       ...: sum(x)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.92 ms per loop

119:~/mypy$ %%timeit x=np.arange(10000)
       ...: np.sum(x)
<caching warning>
100000 loops, best of 3: 18.6 µs per loop
```

Another timing - various ways of making an array.  `fromiter` can be faster than `np.array`; but the builtin `arange` is much better.

```
124:~/mypy$ timeit np.array(range(100000))
10 loops, best of 3: 39.2 ms per loop
125:~/mypy$ timeit np.fromiter(range(100000),int)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.9 ms per loop
126:~/mypy$ timeit np.arange(100000)
The slowest run took 6.93 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
10000 loops, best of 3: 106 µs per loop
```

Use `range` if you intend to work with lists; but use `numpy's` own range if you need to work with arrays.  There is an overhead when creating arrays, so they are more valuable when working with large ones.

==================

On the question of how `np.sum` handles an iterator - it doesn't.  Look at what `np.array` does to such an object:

```
In [12]: np.array(iter(range(10)))
Out[12]: array(<range_iterator object at 0xb5998f98>, dtype=object)
```

It produces a single element array with dtype object.

`fromiter` will evaluate this iterable:

```
In [13]: np.fromiter(iter(range(10)),int)
Out[13]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

`np.array` follows some complicated rules when it comes to converting the input to an array.  It's designed to work primarily, with a list of numbers or nested equal length lists.

If you have questions of how a `np` function handles a non-array object, first check what `np.array` does to that object.