# How to parse a Timestamp() with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, collections

I am iterating over a dictionary that contains data from a SQL database and I want to count the number of times that `user` values appear between `initial_date` and `ending_date`, however, I am having some problems when I try to parse the Timestamp values. This is the code I have

```
initial_date = datetime(2017,09,01,00,00,00)
ending_date  = datetime(2017,09,30,00,00,00)

dictionary sample that I got

sample = {'id': 100008222, 'sector name': 'BONGOX', 'site name': 'BONGO', 'region': 'EMEA', 
'open date': Timestamp('2017-09-11 00:00:00'), 'mtti': '16', 'mttr': '1', 'mttc': '2','user':'John D.'},
{'id': 100008234, 'sector name': 'BONGOY', 'site name': 'BONGO', 'region': 'EMEA', 
'open date': Timestamp('2017-09-09 12:05:00'), 'mtti': '1', 'mttr': '14', 'mttc': '7','user':'John D.'}
{'id': 101108234, 'sector name': 'BONGOA', 'site name': 'BONGO', 'region': 'EMEA', 
'open date': Timestamp('2017-09-01 10:00:00'), 'mtti': '1', 'mttr': '12', 'mttc': '1','user':'John C.'}
{'id': 101108254, 'sector name': 'BONGOB', 'site name': 'BONGO', 'region': 'EMEA', 
'open date': Timestamp('2017-09-02 20:00:00'), 'mtti': '2', 'mttr': '19', 'mttc': '73','user':'John C.'}
```

This is the code that I use to count the number of times `user` values appear between `initial_date` and `ending_date`

```
from datetime import time, datetime
from collections import Counter 

#This approach does not work  
Counter([li['user'] for li in sample if initial_date < dateutil.parser.parse(time.strptime(str(li.get(
'open date'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") < ending_date])
```

The code from above does not work because I encountered the error `decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, Timestamp found`

I have two questions:

1. How can I parse this Timestamp value that I encountered in these dictionaries?
2. I read in this post [Why Counter is slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594940/why-is-collections-counter-so-slow) that Collections.Counter is a slow method compared to other approaches to count the number of times an item appears. If want to avoid using Counter.Collections, how can I achieve my desired result of counting the number of times `user` values appear between these dates?

Comment: have a look at this:
https://medium.com/@eleroy/10-things-you-need-to-know-about-date-and-time-in-python-with-datetime-pytz-dateutil-timedelta-309bfbafb3f7

Comment: in your case you need to get the string out of the Timestamp object, or better compare actual UTC timestamps, which is much easier

Comment: btw, psycopg converts dates to Datetime objects by default, so did you simply try Counter([li['user'] for li in sample if initial_date < li.get(
'open date') < ending_date])

Comment: @MrE how can I compare the actual UTC timestamps?

Comment: what is Timestamp? where does this come from? is it from your ORM? Which ORM do you use?

Comment: BTW, tried `Counter([li['user'] for li in sample if initial_date < li.get( 'open date') < ending_date])` and got `Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'date'`

Comment: Check what Timestamp methods are available to convert to either a string or a date or datetime object.

Comment: @stovfl suggests dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(s['open date'])

Comment: I am retrieving data from a SQL Server Database. Timestamp is generally used as a mechanism for version-stamping table rows. The timestamp data type is just an incrementing number and does not preserve a date or a time. To record a date or time, use a datetime data type.

Comment: The solution from @stovl throws the error `an integer is required (got type Timestamp)`

Comment: A possible solution might be to convert this Timestamp to string and then retrieve the data that is between parenthesis.

Comment: ok, so that's what I suspected. You need to figure out to cast a Timestamp into something useful.The easiest way is use your debugger to get access to the Timestamp object, and figure out what methods it has. Or find the documentation for it and get the info from there. I just don't know where this is from and googleing 'Timestamp' leads nowhere.

Comment: re: convert to string: if Timestamp was convertible to string, str(Timestamp) should have worked.

Comment: Indeed, I also googled for `Timestamp` but this lead me to few options.

Comment: what ORM do you use? it must be an object generated by the ORM. is it SQLAlchemy?something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `Timestamp.to_datetime()` to convert to a `datetime` object

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: How can I parse this Timestamp value that I encountered in these dictionaries?

Using `class Timestampe` from `pandas`

```
from pandas import Timestamp
```

1. Using `Counter()`

   ```
   # Initialize a Counter() object
   c = Counter()

   # Iterate data
   for s in sample:
       # Get a datetime from Timestamp
       dt = s['open date'].to_pydatetime()

       # Compare with ending_date
       if dt < ending_date:
           print('{} < {}'.format(dt, ending_date))

           # Increment the Counter key=s['user']
           c[s['user']] += 1
   print(c)
   ```

   > **Output**:
   >
   > ```
   > 2017-09-11 00:00:00 < 2017-09-30 00:00:00
   > 2017-09-09 12:05:00 < 2017-09-30 00:00:00
   > 2017-09-01 10:00:00 < 2017-09-30 00:00:00
   > 2017-09-02 20:00:00 < 2017-09-30 00:00:00
   > Counter({'John C.': 2, 'John D.': 2})
   > ```

> **Question**:  If want to avoid using Counter.Collections, how can I achieve my desired result of counting

2. Without `Counter()`

   ```
   # Initialize a Dict object
   c = {}
   # Iterate data
   for s in sample:
       # Get a datetime from Timestamp
       dt = s['open date'].to_pydatetime()

       # Compare with ending_date
       if dt < ending_date:
           # Add key=s['user'] to Dict if not exists
           c.setdefault(s['user'], 0)

           # Increment the Dict key=s['user']
           c[s['user']] += 1
   print(c)
   ```

   > **Output**:
   >
   > ```
   > {'John D.': 2, 'John C.': 2}
   > ```

***Tested with Python: 3.4.2***

Comment: There is an error. I've got `an integer is required (got type Timestamp)` :(