# Calculate rolling sum of array in PySpark and save as dict?

Tags: pyspark

Given an input like this:

```
timestamp     vars 
2             [1,2,3]
2             [1,2,4]
3             [1,2]
4             [1,3]
5             [1,3]
```

I need to keep a rolling count of each of the indices. The tried expanding the array into a one hot encoding ([1,2,3,5] -> [0,1,1,1,0,1]) and adding but this can get arbitrarily big (> 1 million), so I want to maintain it as a dict. Something like below. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

```
timestamp     vars 
2             {1:1, 2:1, 3:1}
2             {1:2, 2:2, 3:1, 4:1}
3             {1:3, 2:3, 3:1, 4:1}
4             {1:4, 2:3, 3:2, 4:1}
5             {1:5, 2:3, 3:3, 4:1}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest you to maintain a hashmap and increment the count there and fetch it while creating the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Sample Dataframe :

```
+---+------------+
| ID|         arr|
+---+------------+
|  1|         [0]|
|  2|      [0, 1]|
|  3|   [0, 1, 2]|
|  4|[0, 1, 2, 3]|
|  1|         [0]|
|  1|         [0]|
|  3|   [0, 1, 2]|
|  0|          []|
+---+------------+
```

Using the following function which uses Collection counter:

```
def arr_operation(arr):
   from collections import Counter
   return dict(Counter(arr))
```

Creating UDF for `arr_operation` function in the following manner :

```
udf_dist_count =  udf(arr_operation,MapType(IntegerType(), IntegerType()))
```

And calling the to create a new column:

```
final_df = df.withColumn("Dict",udf_dist_count("arr"))
```

The results will be like :

```
+---+------------+--------------------------------+
|ID |arr         |Dict                            |
+---+------------+--------------------------------+
|1  |[0]         |[0 -> 1]                        |
|2  |[0, 1]      |[0 -> 1, 1 -> 1]                |
|3  |[0, 1, 2]   |[0 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 1]        |
|4  |[0, 1, 2, 3]|[0 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 1, 3 -> 1]|
|1  |[0]         |[0 -> 1]                        |
|1  |[0]         |[0 -> 1]                        |
|3  |[0, 1, 2]   |[0 -> 1, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 1]        |
|0  |[]          |[]                              |
+---+------------+--------------------------------+
```

The argument about collection Counter being slow in a distributed environment has been explained in a good manner in the answer to this question [Why is Collections.counter so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594940/why-is-collections-counter-so-slow)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest `Counter` from `collections`:

```
In [1]: from collections import Counter                                                                                                                             

In [2]: count = Counter()                                                                                                                                           

In [3]: count.update([1,2,4])                                                                                                                                       

In [4]: count                                                                                                                                                       
Out[4]: Counter({1: 1, 2: 1, 4: 1})

In [5]: count.update([1,2,3])                                                                                                                                       

In [6]: count                                                                                                                                                       
Out[6]: Counter({1: 2, 2: 2, 4: 1, 3: 1})

In [7]: count.update([2,3,5])                                                                                                                                       

In [8]: count                                                                                                                                                       
Out[8]: Counter({1: 2, 2: 3, 4: 1, 3: 2, 5: 1})
```

Comment: that is not for pyspark.

Comment: @salt-die, Do you have a suggestion for PySpark?

Comment: My suggestion is to use Counter.  Does PySpark not include python's standard library?

Comment: @salt-die yes it does have the library but it will not work in a distributed manner. ur suggestion would be used in a UDF and they are extremely slow for big data tasks

Comment: You can create new Counters by adding to count if you don't want to mess with mutable objects.