# Python List and count all unique values in list

Tags: python, list, unique-values

I have a list:

`originalList = ['Item1', 'Item1', 'Item1', 'Item2', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']`

I need to create two lists based off of the `originalList`

The first list I need, should list all unique items, such as:

`['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']`

While the other should list the count of each unique value:

`[3, 2, 1, 1]`

Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) in the following way:

```
from collections import Counter
res = dict(Counter(originalList))
```

And getting the keys will give the resulted list and the values will be the count of each element.

To get the 2 lists:

```
keys, values = map(list, zip(*d.items()))
```

Comment: This is great! However, I would need two lists and is new to python. How can I create the two lists based off of the newly created dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

```
originalList = ['Item1', 'Item1', 'Item1', 'Item2', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']

unique = sorted(set(originalList))

frequency = [originalList.count(x) for x in unique]

print(unique)
print(frequency)

>>> [3, 2, 1, 1]
>>> ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']
```

Use `set` to remove duplicates and `sorted` to order the list, this will give you the unique list

Then count the frequency of each unique item in the original list

Answer (score 1):

I agree that you can use `Counter` like [David S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8890604/david-s) mentioned, but if you're after the lists, you can call the list() constructor on the dict's .keys() and .values(). The complete code is something like:

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(originalList)  # Counter is a subclass of dict

# for ['Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3', 'Item4']:
list_1 = list(counts.keys())

# for [3, 2, 1, 1]
list_2 = list(counts.values())
```

Answer (score 1):

The way mentioned by Jordan Engstrom can fetch you your answer.
Another way can be:

```
unique_list = sorted(list(set(originalList)))
count_list = []
for item in unique_list:
    count_list.append(original_list.count(item))
```

For less number of items in a list *.count()* should run faster than Counter.
[Why is Collections.counter so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594940/why-is-collections-counter-so-slow#:%7E:text=Counter%20was%20implemented%20using%20python,is%20still%206%20times%20faster.)
You can read more about Counter's performance in this thread.