# My code does execute for small sample but not for a large

Tags: python, large-data, word-count, find-occurrences

I try to count the frequency of word occurances in a variable. The variables counts more than 700.000 observations. The output should return a dictionary with the words that occured the most. I used the code below to do this:

```
d1 = {}
for i in range(len(words)-1):
    x=words[i]
    c=0
    for j in range(i,len(words)):
        c=words.count(x)
    count=dict({x:c})
    if x not in d1.keys():
        d1.update(count)
```

I've runned the code for the first 1000 observations and it worked perfectly. The output is shown below:

```
[('semantic', 23),
 ('representations', 11),
 ('models', 10),
 ('task', 10),
 ('data', 9),
 ('parser', 9),
 ('language', 8),
 ('languages', 8),
 ('paper', 8),
 ('meaning', 8),
 ('rules', 8),
 ('results', 7),
 ('performance', 7),
 ('parsing', 7),
 ('systems', 7),
 ('neural', 6),
 ('tasks', 6),
 ('entailment', 6),
 ('generic', 6),
 ('te', 6),
 ('natural', 5),
 ('method', 5),
 ('approaches', 5)]
```

When I try to run it for 100.000 observations, it keeps running. I've tried it for more than 24 hours and it still doesn't execute. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Define a dictionary and iterate once over the list. Everytime you see a new word you add it as a key with a value of 1, otherwise if the word already exists in the dictionary just increase its value.

Comment: That makes sence, I'm relatively new to python so maybe you can help me to provide the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`.

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(words)
print(counts.most_common(20))
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jon answer is the best in your case, however in some cases `collections.counter` will be slower than iteration. (specially if afterwards you don't need to sort by frequency) as I asked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594940/why-is-collections-counter-so-slow)

You can count frequencies by iteration.

```
d1 = {}
for item in words:
  if item in d1.keys():
    d1[item] += 1
  else:
    d1[item] = 1

# finally sort the dictionary of frequencies
print(dict(sorted(d1.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])))
```

But again, for your case, using @Jon answer is faster and more compact.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#...
for i in range(len(words)-1):
    #...
    #...
    for j in range(i,len(words)):
        c=words.count(x)
    #...
    if x not in d1.keys():
        #...
```

I've tried to highlight the problems your code is having above. In english this looks something like:

*"Count the number of occurences of each word after the word I'm looking at, repeatedly, for every word in the whole list. Also, look through the whole dictioniary I'm building **again** for every word in the list, while I'm building it."*

This is way more work than you need to do; you only need to look at each word in the list once. You *do* need to look in the dictionary once for every word, but looking at `d1.keys()` makes this far slower by converting the dictionary to another list and looking through the whole thing. The following code will do what you want, much more quickly:

```py
words = ['able', 'baker', 'charlie', 'dog', 'easy', 'able', 'charlie', 'dog', 'dog']

word_counts = {}

# Look at each word in our list once
for word in words:
    # If we haven't seen it before, create a new count in our dictionary
    if word not in word_counts:
        word_counts[word] = 0

    # We've made sure our count exists, so just increment it by 1
    word_counts[word] += 1

print(word_counts.items())
```

The above example will give:

```
[
    ('charlie', 2),
    ('baker', 1),
    ('able', 2),
    ('dog', 3),
    ('easy', 1)
]
```